# mySQL Query to Join 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables in my mySQL database. Put simply, they are

```
CREATE TABLE hotel (
h_id
)

CREATE TABLE amenities_map (
am_id,
h_id,
amenity_id,
amenity_text
)

CREATE TABLE amenities (
amenity_id,
amenity_name,
amenity,
amenity_text
)
```

Using these tables I am able to display the amenities in a list of hotels, with variable numbers of amenities in each. Now I need to create an admin page to add, change and delete the amenities of each hotel.

I've started with a simple query on the amenities table:

```
$query_amenities = "SELECT * FROM amenities ORDER BY amenity_id ASC";
```

That allows me to build a table showing all the possible amenities.

```
<?php while ($row_amenities = $amenities->fetch_assoc()) {?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row_amenities['amenity_name'] ?></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="amenity[]" value="<?php echo $row_amenities['amenity'] ?>" <?php echo $chk_allinc ?>></td>
<td><input name="amenity_text[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_amenities['amenity_text'] ?>" disabled>
<input type="hidden" name="amenity_id" value="<?php echo $row_amenities['amenity_id'] ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

I can find out which amenities there are in the hotel with

```
$query_amenities2 = "SELECT amenity_id, amenity_text FROM amenities_map WHERE h_id='$h_id'";
```

Now here's where I get stuck. If an amenity_id appears in the amenities2 query, I need to use that amenity_text value in the table in place of the first one. (I also need to mark the relevant checkbox as "checked".) I don't want to put the "amenities2" query inside the "where" loop as that will make it run about 30 times. Is there some way of incorporating it into the "amenities" query instead? Perhaps using JOIN in some way?

Comment: show a sample of what you expect to get out of this. It seems to me like you might need to actually look up how to use joins in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL:**

```sql
SELECT a.amenity_id, a.amenity_name, a.amenity, coalesce(m.amentiy_text, a.amenity_text) as amenity_text
    , case when m.h_id is NULL THEN '' ELSE 'checked' END as Checked
FROM amenities a 
LEFT JOIN amenities_map m on m.amenity_id = a.amenity_id
WHERE m.h_id = '$h_id' 
ORDER BY amenity_id ASC
```

*I only know a little php, but the `$h_id` value in here looks suspiciously like it is dangerously vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Make sure you're using prepared statements for this.*

**PHP:**

```php
<?php while ($row_amenities = $amenities->fetch_assoc()) {?>
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $row_amenities['amenity_name'] ?></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="amenity[]" value="<?php echo $row_amenities['amenity'] ?>" <?php echo $row_amenities['Checked'] ?>></td>
   <td><input name="amenity_text[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_amenities['amenity_text'] ?>" disabled>
       <input type="hidden" name="amenity_id" value="<?php echo $row_amenities['amenity_id'] ?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That's fantastic. I spent a little time understanding what you had done there, which has now taught me a little bit more about mySQL. The only thing I've had to do was remove the WHERE line as that was limiting the query to only values that have been selected.
No worries about the sql injection vulnerability: I was just trying to present this to StackOverflow in the simplest possible way.